# Power BI - filtro dashboard dados de varias planilhas

Tags: powerbi

Estou aprendendo power bi,e tenho uma situação que não consegui encontrar uma solução sozinho por aqui.

Situação: tenho uma pasta do excel e nela 12 abas referente cada mês do ano, a tabela de distribuição dos dados é a mesma em todos meses, com o seguinte cabeçalho - nome, cpf, pagto, tipo produto.
Tenho um dashboard com um gráfico de barras onde mostro a evolução do tipo produto por cpf, mas mostra apenas do mês de janeiro que selecionei os campos de dados na tabela importada para o powerBi. Todas os outros meses foram importados também.

Problema: como faço um filtro para selecionar o mês e o gráfico atualizar, ex. quero ver março mostra somente março, ou quero ver junho mostra junho ou seleciona todos os meses e o gráfico atualiza.

Não sei se fui claro o suficiente, mas estou com esta dificuldade.
Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se existe um motivo, mas facilitaria (e muito) se você planificasse os dados, colocando todas as entradas (linhas) em uma única planilha (aba do Excel), e incluir uma coluna de data, isso vai dar um trabalho no inicio, mas no final verá que é melhor para fazer a análise. Por exemplo:

| Data | Nome | CPF | Pagto | Tipo Produto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25/12/2023 | Paulo | aaaaa | 010 | Uva |
| 04/01/2023 | João | nnnnn | 123 | Banana |
| 15/01/2023 | Maria | xxxxx | 321 | Maça |
| 04/02/2023 | Pedro | yyyyy | 456 | Abacate |

Se fizer assim, poupará o trabalho de desenvolver um [PowerQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/power-query/power-query-ui) para tratar os dados na hora de importar para o PowerBI.

Bom... com os dados planificados em uma única planilha, abra o PowerBI e selecione os dados (estou usando o PowerBi Desktop, mas nas outras versões é semelhante):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Marque a planilha e veja os dados, agora com uma coluna de data.

Crie e configure o gráfico (fiz pelo que entendi da sua pergunta, faça como precisar...).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No gráfico, use as setas na parte de cima para navegar entre os diferentes níveis das datas Dia, Mês, Trimestre e Ano.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então inclua um elemento do tipo "Segmentação de Dados" e ligue o Campo "Data" à ele. Isso irá incluir um filtro dinâmico no seu formulário!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra forma de aplicar o filtro é usando o filtro geral (por página, elemento, etc.), o tipo certo depende do que você precisa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: dwpessoa, já pensei nesta solução proposta, mas continuando dentro da linha de pensamento, creio que não me expressei de forma clara. O que desejo é uma forma de fazer um filtro para escolher qual tabela ou aba da planilha vai apresentar os dados no gráfico, se escolho no filtro a tabela/aba nomeada janeiro apresenta somente este, caso contrario escolho outro ou posso selecionar todos os meses. Mas adianto que me ajudou muito e agradeço pela colaboração.